# Как правильно работать с будильниками в UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, уведомления

**Итак, что мне нужно получить:**
Чтобы сработал будильник после его установки.

**Что получаю:**
Если приложение не закрывать, то будильники работают, как положено. Но если приложение закрыть, то стек этих пушей будет очищен. Проверил это так - установил будильник, убедился в его работе при запущенном приложении, завел снова и закрыл приложение, время срабатывания наступает, а пуш-уведомления нет.
Будильник взвожу так:

```
ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
{
    Scenario = ToastScenario.Alarm,
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        TitleText = new ToastText()
        {
             Text = "Пора на работу!\n Начало в " + appointment.StartTime.ToString()
        }
    },
    Audio = new ToastAudio()
    {
        Src = new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm")
    },
    Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Buttons = { new ToastButtonSnooze(), new ToastButtonDismiss() }
    },
};
var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
ScheduledToastNotification stn = new ScheduledToastNotification(content.GetXml(), alarmTime, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), 3);
stn.Id = appointment.AppointmentID;
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(stn);
```

Comment: Если не найду решения очистки стека с пушами при закрытии приложения, то сделаю так - вместо добавления в стек пуша, я на это время буду взводить триггер фоновой задачи. И когда триггер сработает тут же показывать тост.

Comment: Имхо, без фоновой задачи не обойтись

Answer (score 0):

По-моему надо в манифесте зарегистрировать фоновую задачу и в `App.xaml.cs` указать `await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();`